# WordPress plugin adds the number 1 to content if activated

Tags: php, wordpress

My WP plugin bizarely adds the numeral 1 to the content if the plugin is active.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'poc_shop_cart_button_filter' );

function poc_shop_cart_button_filter($the_content) {

        $new_content = $the_content;

        $new_content .= include(WP_CONTENT_DIR . "/custom_php/shop-cart-button.php");

        return $new_content;

}
```

This is the page I am including with the plugin:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['_abs_34287GjNW'])){
$cookieID = htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE['_abs_34287GjNW'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
} else {
    $cookieID = '';
}

$supplierID = get_bloginfo('name');

require(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/custom_php/includes/connectDB.php');

try {

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
                FROM `shoppingCart`
                WHERE supplierID=:supplierID
                AND cookieID = :cookieID";

    $sqlprep = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $ar_val = array(':supplierID'=>$supplierID,
                    ':cookieID'=>$cookieID);

        if($sqlprep->execute($ar_val)) {
            while($row = $sqlprep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){

                if($row->count=='' || $row->count==0){
                    $count='0';
                } else{
                    $count = $row->count;
                }

            }
        }

        if($count == 1){
            $items = "item";
        } else {
            $items = "items";
        }

            if(is_page(array(48)) || $count < 1){
                echo '<div class="shopCartNoButton">';
                echo "<img src='" . get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/cart-icon.png' alt=''>";
                echo " <b>$count $items </b>";
                echo '</div><div class="clearFix"></div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="shopCartButton">';
                echo "<img src='" . get_template_directory_uri() . "/images/cart-icon.png' alt=''>";
                echo " <b>$count $items </b>";
                echo "&nbsp; <a href='office-seating/checkout/' class='btn btn-warning'> Checkout >></a>";
                echo '</div><div class="clearFix"></div>';
            }


    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

[image]

So the solution to this after MUCH Googling is as follows:

```
$filename = get_include_contents('somefile.php');

function get_include_contents($filename) {
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
    return false;
}
```

The code:

```
include( $filename );
```

returns the included file + the value 1 because the include was successful. 
One must use output buffering to [include a PHP file into a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and not return the value 1 with the returned file contents.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. It is because `include` returns value of the call, i.e. "true" or 1 when WordPress render data via `echo`. Just use `file_get_contents` it will help.

Comment: See my solution added to the edited question above. file_get_contents() returns the file as text string, does not interpret the PHP within the file.